# Paint on next frame on Windows's graphics?

Tags: c#, winapi, paint

I need to draw some things on the screen for **only 1 frame**.
Things such as a line of text.

I tried to achieve this with moving windows, but I failed. I cannot get them to show for only 1 frame (8-16 msec), either by showing/hiding or moving in and out of place.

Is there any way to do this?

(Urgh, for the curious, I'm doing this for someone else, so rationalizing over the reason why this needs to be done is useless.)

**Edit**: Last thing I tried:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    static Random rand = new Random();


    public void ShowString(string s)
    {
        this.label1.Text = s; // Has .AutoSize = true
        this.Size = this.label1.Size;

        var bnds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        bnds.Size -= this.Size;

        this.Location = new Point(rand.Next(bnds.X, bnds.Right), rand.Next(bnds.Y, bnds.Bottom));
    }


    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Location.X != -10000 && Location.Y != -10000)
        {
            Location = new Point(-10000, -10000);

            timer1.Interval = Program.interval; // How long to wait before showing two things.
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Interval = Program.delay; // For how long to show.

            ShowString("just something to test");
        }
    }
}
```

And before that:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    static Random rand = new Random();


    public void ShowString(string s)
    {
        this.label1.Text = s; // Has .AutoSize = true
        this.Size = this.label1.Size;

        var bnds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        bnds.Size -= this.Size;

        this.Location = new Point(rand.Next(bnds.X, bnds.Right), rand.Next(bnds.Y, bnds.Bottom));
    }


    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Interval = Program.interval;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Form2_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Location.X != -10000 && Location.Y != -10000)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Program.delay); // Dirty cheat, but I was just trying.
            this.Location = new Point(-10000, -10000);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowString("just something to test");
    }
}
```

Comment: One frame of the screen or graphics device. I stated what I tried and failed.

Comment: I am fairly sure that my screen displays 60 frames per second. Those are the frames I am referring to. The code that I tried was for moving windows - basically a workaround. I'm going to add the last thing I tried.

Comment: That's not a frame. That's a hardware refresh cycle, usually expressed as something like 60 MHz or 72 MHz. It has nothing to do with Windows graphics; it's a graphics hardware operation. A frame is typically something used in animation such as videos, which is why I asked in the first place. :-) It's highly doubtful that using Windows GDI/GDI+ you're going to obtain that kind of timing.

Comment: I too thought that GDI(+) might not help me with this. I haven't seen any methods to access this. I thought the only way would be accessing the virtual graphics device that windows uses directly, somehow, and draw on its memory, again somehow.

Comment: Kendall, I am not looking specifically for a WinForms solution. What I tried just happened to be using WinForms.

Comment: @Kendall: I removed the tag you added, because the question asks about any method of solving the problem. It has nothing to do with WinForms; it's a Windows API question.

Comment: I doubt that GDI/GDI+ will let you do this; you'll almost certainly have to use Direct2D.

Comment: If only I knew how...

Comment: Google 'Direct2D tutorial'.  D2D is an advanced API, so there's likely going to be a steep learning curve...

Comment: I have used it before a bit, but I have not a clue about how to use it on Windows's virtual graphics device.